# Symfony 4 validation Entity/DTO existence

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony4, dto

For example, I have a password reminder form. How add annotation for email existence in database validation, for example **@Assert\Exists**.

```
class PasswordRemindRequest
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    private $email;

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->$email;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to write your custom validator https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html where to check if email exists or not in database.

Comment: Or use callback constraints => https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html

Comment: OK, thanks, I will write custom constraint. I thought it could be solved differently. Laravel has it better solved

Comment: @Alex => @Assert\Exists doesn't exist in Symfony. I write this as example